# Selecting multiple attributes in Fasterize?

Tags: r, raster

Are there capable options for selecting more than one attribute in the `fasterize` package?

For example, when using `rasterize`, it automatically selects all the attributes, i.e.

```
r.2010 <- ebird_buff.2010 %>% 
  st_transform(crs = projection(r.2010)) %>% 
  rasterize(r.2010) %>% 
  # remove any empty cells at edges
  trim()

class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1405, 1943, 2729915  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 2316.564, 2316.564  (x, y)
extent     : -9738370, -5237287, 2741885, 5996656  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 6, 28289  (min, max)
attributes :
          ID year locality_id species_observed
 from:     1 2010    L2228604                0
  to : 28289 2010    L1348755                0
```

Though, when using fasterize, it returns a field of 1:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1409, 1946, 2741914  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 2316.564, 2316.564  (x, y)
extent     : -9747636, -5239604, 2730302, 5994340  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1, 1  (min, max)
```

I've noticed that the attributes are credited to the raster if and only if attributes are currently present in the fasterized raster, though this is not necessarily true for rasterize.

i.e.

```
r
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1430, 2052, 2934360  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 2316.564, 2316.564  (x, y)
extent     : -9793968, -5040379, 2716402, 6029088  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs
```

Though, when `r` has an attribute table, then fasterize imitates it:

```
#This is the result when I use r.2010, the first example above, as the raster to be fasterized
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1405, 1943, 2729915  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 2316.564, 2316.564  (x, y)
extent     : -9738370, -5237287, 2741885, 5996656  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1, 1  (min, max)
attributes :
          ID year locality_id species_observed
 from:     1 2010    L2228604                0
  to : 28289 2010    L1348755                0
```

Though, if I wish to select a field, I can alternatively select individual fields likeso:

```
fasterize(r, field = "some_field")
```

Although, I cannot select multiple fields

```
fasterize(r, field = c("some_field_1", "some_field_2"))
```

> Error in fasterize(., r.2019, field = c("some_field_1", "some_field_2")) :
> Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=2].

Is there an efficient method for selecting multiple fields when the raster used in `fasterize` does not have an attribute table, such that the attribute values are taken from the columns in the shapefile?